# How to make a working Copy of Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla

I am running Joomla 1.5

I duplicated the entire Joomla directory from the command line via "cp"
I duplicated the entire MySQL database form within phpMyAdmin

When I run the dup'd site I don't get my selected template, I get the out-of-the-box default template. So I went into Template Manager and made my template the default.

Next the menus are whacky.

So before I proceed to set everything manually, one-by-one, if there something I am missing here as to why when I make an exact copy of everything the new Joomla site does not look exactly like the current one?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.  I assume you followed [Copying a Joomla website](http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website)?  Make sure you follow that exactly.

But I strongly recommend using [Akeeba backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606) instead.  I use it for all my sites and it just works.  It is a free extension that does it all for you.  Might take some initial setup but after that you are set.